# How do I serve dynamic images in Django?

Tags: django

I have a Django app that pulls images from emails and creates thumbnails that I want to display in a view. Since these are not static files, and not files uploaded by users, where should I store them and how do I get a URL that can be placed into the src tag so the client browser will download it?

I'd like to be able to have the view display the image from a template with code something like this:

```
<img src="{{ path }}" />
```

where path evaluates to the URL of the image file.

I'm fairly new to Django so I'm sure I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "save" the thumbnail as a "file".  This does not have to by a file on disk though.

Once you have read the email and extracted the image, assuming the image is attached to the email and is not an HTML link. Your attached image is now in memory.  You will save the image exactly as you would save to disk, except you save to an io.BytesIO() stream in memory then you return that in your route as "image/png" which you use as the path to your img tag.

You might run into issues if you are doing this for many images because you are storing all in memory. You might have better performance to save the thumbnail into your static directory and then link to that.  You can clean up your thumbnails periodically if you do that.